# Complex SVN Checkout Procedure?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have a repository configured like this:

```
+---CollectionA
|   \---project1
|       \---trunk
|           \---sourcecode
|       \---tags
|           \---rel-1
|   \---project2
|       \---trunk
|           \---sourcecode
|       \---tags
|   \---project3
|       \---trunk
|           \---sourcecode
|       \---tags
|           \---rel-1
```

I'd like to checkout any project tagged `rel-1` as that project.  In this case I'd get `project1` and `project3` in my workspace, but not `project2`.

All `projectN` are Eclipse Java projects.

I'm using Eclipse/Subversive, but I'm open to using Tortoise or the command line (windows) if I need to.

**Edit**: Currently, to do this, I'll have to go through my 30-some projects and checkout each tag individually.  Is there a way to do this without going through each project individually?

Comment: Not sure whether it's your case, or not, but having to do such things for about 30 projects is a sign to consider changes in repository structure...

Comment: @maxim1000, we're developing OSGi based applications, where one bundle is in fact reused in multiple projects.  The repository format *should* make the task straight forward, unfortunately I had some trouble with buckminster as an automatic build tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to write a command line script in order to do this.  There's no way I know of to do this using Tortoise or an integrated IDE/SVN tool since this is an uncommon (in my experience) type of checkout operation.

You can ask svn on the command line as to whether a directory exists using the **svn list** command.

Then you could check the output (maybe it returns a non-zero value if the directory isn't found, or you could parse the output stream) to determine whether the tag exists.  Add the projects that contain the tag to a list, then checkout those projects.

Something like this:

```
For each project in myProjects:
   exec "svn list " myRepositoryPath + "/" + myProject + "/tags/directory"
```

Answer (score 1):

We use scripting to achieve the efficiency you're looking for.  Create a generic checkout script that looks to a second manifest file that contains the tags/branches/trunk names that you want to checkout for each module.

I've toyed with the idea of creating a module that contains "project" directories with externs to the specific tags/branches/trunks of the projects' modules combination but I've never gotten around to doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do this a lot, you could create another directory in your repository, and give it the `svn:externals` property. List all the relevant projects as externals. Then when you check out the new directory, you'll get all the projects checked out inside it.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the previous answers, you could user the scripts to create a Eclipse Team Project Set file, to directly import all the projects at once.
Couldn't find a directe reference to the "psf file format", but you'll get the idea with [this example](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/development/cvs_setup.php) and checking the eclipse help.